# How to publish all database projects in a solution in one operation?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2013, sqlproj

Back in VIsual Studio 2010, it was possible to right-click on the solution and pick "Deploy Solution", and it would push all database projects to their respective configured database server(s).

In Visual Studio 2013, for database projects "publish" has taken the place previously held by "deploy".

However, I can't seem to find a way to publish *all* database projects in a solution in a single operation. Rather, it is necessary to "publish" each database project individually. Even when in the configuration manager the database projects are set to "deploy", "deploy solution" does not do anything at all for a solution that contains a mix of database and C# projects.

Is there for database projects (.sqlproj file type) in Visual Studio 2013 a feature functionally equivalent to "Deploy Solution" as found in Visual Studio 2010?